Managing a Large Number of Artifacts in Artifactory OSS and Migration from Pro
I am currently using Artifactory version 6.9.0 and have a repository serving approximately 130,000 artifacts. I would like to know if this volume is manageable with Artifactory OSS, or if there are specific limitations I should be aware of when using the OSS version.
Additionally, I am interested in understanding the process for migrating all of these artifacts from my existing Pro version of Artifactory to a new OSS installation. Are there best practices or tools available to facilitate this migration?
Thank you for your assistance!

I am also interested in this. Are you using "OSS" as a generic term or do you mean specifically the OSS vs JCR vs CPP CE? I'm digging into this because of the license change (currently on Pro) and see that each of the three editions handles different artifact types. https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-hosting-models-documentation/artifactory-comparison-matrix

I'm using OSS because it fits most of my package types, but the question may also apply to other editions. I'm researching this for the same reason (the Pro license change). Unfortunately, as I noticed, the OSS edition offers only five package types for 'freemium', so it is very limited and could become paid later
